# Media recorder stopped notification

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, sdk

I need help setting up a notification everytime the media recorder is stopped for a certain amount of time. My program starts and stops media recorder often but its usually instant so I need the code to say everytime media recorder is null for say 10 seconds call notification method.

Comment: When you say that your "program starts and stops media recorder often but its is usually instant" what is this instant time duration? Also, the end of your question is not clear. Can you be a bit more elaborate?

Comment: It's made to stop it and start it again a few lines of code later. And this is in a  continueous loop. The problem is sometimes as the program runs the media recorder stops without starting. I need a way of knowing when that happens.so I figured if I can set up a notification to come on when the media recorder is stopped I would know. But it can be just a simple -if (null)- because then it would be triggered everytime the program loops. There has to be a time counter of some sort

Comment: When you call `MediaPlayer.start()`, the playback runs on a different thread.  As you said that you are calling `MediaPlayer.stop()` on the object a **few** lines later, which might happen in order of microseconds. And, the thread that is actually doing the playback might take more time than that to start. It depends on how it is scheduled by your scheduler. Also, I am not sure why do you specify this condition of `null`. Once the `MediaPlayer` object is initialised, why would it be null. Correct me if I understood anything wrong.

Comment: Also, please tell what is that you are actually trying to do in the question itself. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Not media player I'm talking about media recorder.  My program calls media recorder and loops it continuesly . Again problem is sometimes it doesn't loop and just stops recording. I need to know when that happens

Comment: Can you please say what is it that you are trying to achieve from a use case point of view?

Comment: Continuous recording looped every 10 minutes

Comment: Do you want to save the recorded audio (every 10 minutes) in a file or do you want to do some kind of real-time processing as well?

Comment: Well if I press the save button it will save otherwise overwrite the previous